# How to add .bib file to .Rnw file for sweaving in Rstudio

Tags: r, sweave, bibtex, citations

How do I add a .bib file to my .Rnw file that I'm trying to Sweave? I have my .bib file in my working directory which is also where .Rnw file is located. I try the following:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{DronesBib}
```

I got no error, the file compiles but theres no bibliography showing

Comment: If you are using RStudio, see if this helps http://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/

Comment: It's not very clearly to me what's going on in those directions. The code isn't in context. I implemented it a few different ways and they all produced compile errors. Is there anyone out there who is a user of sweave and .bib files? Im sure there is. This is the simplest of most simple questions. I usually use r markdown but I'm working on something a bit fancier so I switched to latex so I'm new to this but I can't imagine others don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: I tried the advice I saw on setting the TEXINPUTS, BIBINPUTS and BSTINPUTS to the path where the bib file is located (my wd) but no luck.

Comment: The workflow to get a bibliography is `pdflatex -- bibtex -- pdflatex -- pdflatex`, so you porably need to compile a few more times to get this to work.